# How do i calc what side the ball is of the rect?

Tags: 2d, game-mechanics, computational-geometry

I have this nice drawing:

http://bildr.no/view/1085283

I know the ball's center and the rectangle's center, but how do I know (programming C#) what side of the rectangle the ball is?

By my drawing, the answer in this case should be the right side.

Comment: Is the rectangle always axis-aligned, or does it have an orientation?

Answer (score 2):

What side of A is B on? Using [this info](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/) (see Solution 3) you can determine which side of a line A point (or points) B, is on.

For your particular scenario, you need to check which of four sides of the rectangle, the circle is in. In this case, you can treat your circle as just it's centre/origin point. Now you need to look at the rectangle like this:

```
\       /
 \ q1  /<--one of the two lines bordering quadrant 4
  *---*
  |\ /|<---rectangle edge for quadrant 4
q4| x |q2
  |/ \|
  *---*
 / q3  \<--one of the two lines bordering quadrant 4
/       \
```

The `q`'s stand for quadrant or *side* of the rectangle you're on; the numberings are abritrary, but just show you that the centre point can lie in any of these 4 distinct quadrants. You need to determine that the circle centre is:

- to the correct side of each of the two lines bordering that quadrant (the diagonal ones in the drawing above), i.e. it must lie between them;

**AND**

- to the correct side of the rectangle-edge that lies within that quadrant (between the aforementioned diagonal lines.

This will tell you if the point falls in to the bowl-shaped area on each of the four sides of the rectangle shown above.

The "correct" side is determined by you, when you construct the formula in the link given  above. It depends on whether you specify a line as PQ or it's reverse, QP. This is known as [winding order](http://www.codesampler.com/d3dbook/chapter_05/chapter_05.htm) (see "Winding Order of Vertices").

Comment: Seems like a lot more work than just doing a dot product. Additionally, your solution is limited to rectangle only.

Comment: @NicFoster Not getting any upvotes, eh? Hmm.

Comment: You've avoided the context of the original comment. You don't agree that this is a lot of work to find the side of the shape a position lies?

Comment: I'd say this answer is slightly more intuitive, albeit not by much. It certainly doesn't take any credibility from your own. If you've ever tried to explain what the dot or cross product are, visually, you'll see that it becomes less trivial to follow the logic in solving the problem as a whole. Many take the mathematics behind those factors for granted, and use them without understanding what they are actually doing. And no, I don't agree. The conciseness of my answer in relation to yours speaks to that fact. Writing a method `checkSide(Line l, Point p)` isn't what I'd call onerous.

Comment: Agree with most that, but I do feel like your answer is tailored more towards rectangles specifically, whereas the use of vector math (dot product, unitization) is applicable to just about any shape or situation in both 2D and 3D.

Comment: @NicFoster His question is about rectangles. He makes that quite clear. I'm not answering some other question here; I'm answering the one he asked.

Comment: He may be new to game programming, if he needs a future solution for other cases he will need an entirely new method, I'm sure you understand the benefit to an extensible and reusable solution over many separate and specific ones.

Comment: @NicFoster Yes, let's sit here, twiddling our thumbs and discussing the _ifs_, the _buts_ and the _maybes_... and then write code around that. That seems a sound software engineering principle, doesn't it? Or I'll just give the simplest solution I know of... oh, I already have.

Comment: Yea, I think we're done here. I prefer to teach people new to game programming stuff they can reuse in the future for more than a one-off situation, but to each their own. We can just agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by giving all of my game entities a position (Vector 2D/3D), and a rotation (Matrix 3x3). Your rotation matrix will have either a column or row for its forward, up, and right vectors. In the case of a 2D game, the 'up' vector is unnecessary.

First you get the vector from your square's center to the ball's center.

```
Vector2 direction = ball.position - square.position;
```

Now you normalize/unitize the vector to make it represent a unit-length direction

```
direction.Unitize();

// Here's a method to unitize a 2D vector
void Vector2::Unitize()
{
    const float inverseLength = 1.0f / Length();
    x *= inverseLength;
    y *= inverseLength;        
}
```

Unitizing requires knowing the length of your vector, so we make a helper method for that as well

```
float Length(void) const { return sqrtf( x * x + y * y ); }
```

Ok, now that we have a direction from the square to the ball, defined earlier by the 2D vector we called `direction`, we now do a dot-product between that direction, and the square's right vector (the direction the represents its right-hand side). For this example, in your image, let's say the square is facing toward the top of the image, and that the ball is on the square's right-hand side. Doing this dot product will tell us if the ball is on the right-hand or left-hand side of the square.

```
Vector2 squareRightVect; // You would retrieve this from the square's rotation matrix
float dotResult = direction.Dot(squareRightVect);
```

Now we have the `dotResult`, which will be a value between -1 and 1, anything greater than 0 means the ball is on the right side of the square. Based on the image I'd say the dot product would be about 0.85, putting the ball on the right side of the square. If your dot-product gave a result of anything less than zero than the ball is on the left.

And finally, here's your dot-product method:

```
float Dot(const Vector2& rhs) const { return (x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y); }
```

And here are some helpful links if you want to learn more about the processes involved in the above code:

- Finding length ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [game dev blog](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-finding.html))
- Finding direction between two points ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), [game dev blog](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-finding_07.html))
- Dot-product ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), [game dev blog](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-dot-products.html))